# Sending Authorization to Rails API via React Native (JWT)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, react-native, jwt

After successfully working an auth flow between React Native and Rails using JWT, I'm now trying to submit data to rails to change information on the application. This involves me sending an HTTP header with an 'Authorization' key. I'm not sure how exactly I need to format the value (or whether I need to include both the auth Token and the user id) so kind of stuck. Hard to find information about it too as it seems an unusual stack combo.

I'll include all the code I believe is relevant.

This is the action for sending to rails. It sends and the profileName data that I want to be submitted is in the params on the rails server log. Note the `'Authorization': currentUserToken`

```
 export function changeProfileName( profileName ) {
   return (dispatch, getState) => {
     // I think i need current user.. how to do?
     // const currentUser = getState().user.id
     const currentUserToken = getState().authToken
     fetch ('http://localhost:3000/edit', {
         method: 'POST',
         headers: {
            //what to do here, now user is authorized?
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Authorization': currentUserToken,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         },
         body: JSON.stringify({
             "name": profileName
         })
     }).then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json().then((data) => {
            console.log(data, 'good')
            dispatch({
                type: 'CONFIRM_PROFILE_NAME_CHANGE'
            });
        });
     }
    })
   }
 }
```

This is the authorization that is returning an error in the rails server log and where my confusion is. How do I format my request so I can get a positive authorization response? Perhaps I need to have both the token and the user id (where user id is the key and the token is the value) but I'm not sure how to do this, as in the store the `user` and its attributes are a separate entity than the `userToken` (https://ibb.co/8BwHJpT)

```
    def auth_header
        #requesting the header type of authorization (with token) that we will declare through our api requests
        # { Authorization: 'Bearer <token>' }
        request.headers['Authorization']
    end

    #what does this mean?
    def decoded_token
        if auth_header
            token = auth_header.split(' ')[1]
            # header: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer <token>' }
            begin
                JWT.decode('s3cr3t', true, algorithm: 'HS256')
            rescue JWT::DecodeError
                nil
            end
        end
    end

    #what does this mean?
    def logged_in_user
        #consults decode_token to check the header for valid information
        if decoded_token
            user_id = decoded_token[0]['user_id']
            @user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
        end
    end

    def logged_in?
        #returns true or false
        !!logged_in_user
    end

    def authenticate_request
        #consults logged_in? see see if user is authorized
        render json: { message: 'Please log in' }, status: :unauthorized unless logged_in?
    end
```

Thanks!

Comment: By the look of it you're not passing any token to JWT for decoding, is that intentional ?

Comment: @MuhammadYawarAli How so - ```const currentUserToken = getState().authToken```?

Comment: No, in rails method like: `JWT.decode(token, true, algorithm: 'HS256')`. You must be passing the token coming in request header for decoding.

Comment: Plus, rails has a method to extract request header token for you like:
```
authenticate_with_http_token do |token, options|
  JWT.decode(token, true, algorithm: 'HS256')
 end
```

Comment: comment out the `rescue JWT::DecodeError; nil` and see if you are actually getting an exception.  You probably are.  As Muhammad said, you can't decode a token without passing the token in.

Comment: You guys are right - I'm getting an exception of DecodeError. However I'm then not sure how to pass the token so it will be accepted. I've now changed and logged the token going out with the request but not sure how to format it.

Comment: Read the docs for `JWT.decode`.  You have to pass the *actual token* you got from the request as the first parameter, not `s3cr3t`.